# technique to support urls with https between local and live development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

When I deploy my application, certain urls have to be https.

How can I develop locally and deploy, while being able to support urls that have https?

Is the only way wrapping the url with a function, that determines if you are local or live?

(this is a .net mvc app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For URLs internal to the site always use relative paths.

For URLs that reference external sites you could use a resource file to manage them. That way you only need to update the URLs before deployment in one location.

Comment: relative paths will also come in handy if you change domains too. Also when dealing with https, dont forget about the port number ( some situations might mandate you use something other than 443)